# aspx button click won't save variable value to array

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an aspx website with an array declared at the top of the page just after the inherits clause called Private Input(10) as String and it gets its value from Private strCalculation as String. When I click the store button, the first array value receives strCalculation value, and then the array slot increases by one. However, the page does not retain the strCalculation as I have just had the subtraction button display it in a label and it has no value! Here is the code, with a subtraction equation happening first, where the strCalculation gets its value:

```
Option Strict On
Partial Class Index

Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Private i As Integer = 0
Private Input(10) As String
Private strCalculation As String

Protected Sub btnSubtract_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubtract.Click
    lblMessage.Text = String.Empty
    Dim Numfirst As Double
    Double.TryParse(txtFirstNum.Text, Numfirst)
    Dim Numsecond As Double
    Double.TryParse(txtSecondNum.Text, Numsecond)
    Dim answer = Convert.ToString(Numfirst - Numsecond)
    strCalculation = (Numfirst & " - " & Numsecond & " = " & answer)
    txtResults.Text = strCalculation
    txtResults.Focus()
End Sub

Protected Sub btnStore_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStore.Click
    Input(i) = strCalculation
    i += 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array won't persist because of the page's short lifecycle (per request).  Save it to the session like this:

```
'Is this the firt input?
If Session("InputCount") Is Nothing OrElse Session("InputCount") = "" Then
    Session("InputCount") = "0"
End If

'Set the new value.
Dim intInputCount As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Session("InputCount")) + 1
Session("Input" + intInputCount.ToString()) = strCalculation

'Increment the input count.
Session("InputCount") = intInputCount.ToString()
```

Then to reference the stored inputs:

```
If Not Session("InputCount") Is Nothing OrElse Session("InputCount") <> "" Then

    Dim intRecordCount  = Convert.ToInt32(Session("InputCount"))

    For intCursor As Integer = 1 To intRecordCount

        Dim strCalculation As String = Session("Input" & intCursor.ToString())
        'Do Something with the value.   

    Next

End If
```